# Lightning Design System - Large Buttons

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, style

We're trying to use the LDS classes to create a very large set of buttons. How can I set a button size to say 150x150?

```
<apex:page >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  
    <head>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.lds, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="slds">  

    <a href="#" class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-button--150x150">Large Button</a>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no equivalent class modifiers like `--large` for `slds-button`,you have to add custom css to increase the button size in SLDS,like this:

```
<style>
     .btn-lg{
         height: 44px;
         width: 150px;
      }
<style>
```

add the class to the desired element:

```
<a href="#" class="slds-button slds-button--brand btn-lg">Large Button</a>
```

Comment: Use of the `!important` flag is not exactly best practice. See [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception). It says *Using `!important` is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.*

Comment: @AdrianLarson Inorder to resolve the css conflicts with slds,which might occurs,just trying to be safe by including `!important`.But over use of it,might cause lot of style overriding issue.I got your point.

Comment: You should see it as a *last resort*, and try to solve any conflicts via specificity *first*. Your answer would be improved if you move that out of the main code block imo. I know it can be a royal pain to get css working on salesforce though and it's sometimes necessary.

Comment: @AdrianLarson i have edited the answer,and also thanks for the info.

Comment: You have my vote. I can't say I've never had to resort to `!important` myself. I just try to avoid it when I can. :)

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson - thanks for the work around, I will use it, its a bummer that we cannot set a specific size.